# How to make a Openbox dockapp with GTK?

Tags: gtk, ruby, openbox

I'm using Openbox and I want to make a dock-app (NOTE: not a dock like plank/docky but a dock-app like stalonetray or lal) in GTK+. How do I get the simple app I have written to sit in the dock area?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "gtk3"

module Bang
    class Clock < Gtk::Window
        def initialize(clock_fmt)
            super(:toplevel)
            @label = Gtk::Label.new
            @fmt = clock_fmt
            self.add(@label)
        end
        def start(time)
            GLib::Timeout.add(time) do
                @label.markup = Time.now.strftime(@fmt)
                self.show_all
            end
        end
    end
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
    Gtk.init
    @clock = Bang::Clock.new('%T')
    @clock.signal_connect("destroy") do
        Gtk.main_quit
    end
    @clock.start(1000)
    @clock.show_all
    Gtk.main
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suspect that any tray applet worth its salt is following the [Freedesktop system tray specifications](http://standards.freedesktop.org/systemtray-spec/systemtray-spec-0.2.html) so that every X11 application works on every desktop environment as expected.

[GTK+ 3 certainly follows these specs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStatusIcon.html). That should give you a rough idea of the bindings you'll be using. I've no idea how these are translated through Ruby though.